# Split large file according to value in single column (AWK)

Tags: awk, split, genetic, large-data

I would like to split a large file (10^6 rows) according to the value in the 6th column (about 10*10^3 unique values). However, I can't get it working because of the number of records. It should be easy but it's taking hours already and I'm not getting any further.

I've tried two options:

Option 1

```
awk '{print > $6".txt"}' input.file
awk: cannot open "Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g051570.2.1.txt" for output (Too many open files)
```

Option 2

```
awk '{print > $6; close($6)}' input.file
```

This doesn't cause an error but the files it creates contain only the last line corresponding to 'grouping' value $6

This is the beginning of my file, however, this file doesn't cause an error because it's so small:

```
exon    3688    4407    +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005000.2.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005000.2.1
exon    4853    5604    +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005000.2.1.2    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005000.2.1
exon    7663    7998    +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005000.2.1.3    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005000.2.1
exon    9148    9408    +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005010.1.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005010.1.1
exon    13310   13330   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005020.1.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005020.1.1
exon    13449   13532   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005020.1.1.2    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005020.1.1
exon    13711   13783   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005020.1.1.3    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005020.1.1
exon    14172   14236   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005020.1.1.4    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005020.1.1
exon    14717   14803   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005020.1.1.5    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005020.1.1
exon    14915   15016   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005020.1.1.6    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005020.1.1
exon    22106   22261   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005030.1.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005030.1.1
exon    23462   23749   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005040.1.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005040.1.1
exon    24702   24713   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005050.2.1.3    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005050.2.1
exon    24898   25402   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005050.2.1.2    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005050.2.1
exon    25728   25845   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005050.2.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005050.2.1
exon    36352   36835   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005060.2.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005060.2.1
exon    36916   38132   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005060.2.1.2    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005060.2.1
exon    57089   57096   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005070.1.1.1    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005070.1.1
exon    57329   58268   +   ID=exon:Solyc06g005070.1.1.2    Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005070.1.1
exon    59970   60505   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.24   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    60667   60783   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.23   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    63719   63880   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.22   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    64143   64298   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.21   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    66964   67191   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.20   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    71371   71559   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.19   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    73612   73717   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.18   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    76764   76894   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.17   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    77189   77251   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.16   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    80044   80122   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.15   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
exon    80496   80638   -   ID=exon:Solyc06g005080.2.1.14   Parent=mRNA:Solyc06g005080.2.1
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Option 2, use “>>” instead of “>”, to append.

```
awk '{print >> $6; close($6)}' input.file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, that wasn't to difficult. Glad that you took the time to help me with such a obvious error! Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer AND the question. I have the exact same problem and had been struggling with a good way to do it...

Comment: I've been happily using @Patrice's answer for a long while. Just to add: if your file contains large chunks of consecutive lines with the same column value, you can speed things up greatly by not closing the file unless that value changes: `awk '{if (last != $6) close(last); print >> $6; last = $6}' input.file`.